# ¿Qué debería hacer si respondí una pregunta cuya respuesta es también adecuada en otra respuesta?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, respuesta

Tengo un dilema, hace poco respondí [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495615/java-comparaci%C3%B3n-de-strings-no-se-cumple/) en comentarios de porqué una comparación de Strings con `==` en Java no funcionaba y el OP me pidió que le explicara por qué, a lo que desarrollé una respuesta extensa que consideraba varios casos.

Sin embargo, más tarde me di cuenta que existe [otra pregunta donde encaja mejor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-correctamente-strings-y-objetos-en-java) donde quisiera publicar también mi respuesta, pues considero que tiene detalles que no han sido mencionados como las "*Yoda expressions*" o por qué es preferible usar la clase Objects así como las clases Wrapper. Así mismo esta segunda pregunta está enlazada a [otra pregunta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) por lo que considero que sería mejor publicarla ahí, para que otras personas que visiten SOen y hablen español puedan considerar y ver la respuesta que he escrito (Siendo sincero, creo que la primera pregunta muy probablemente se pierda entre los post).

Mi problema está en que no sé si sea correcto copiar y pegar mi respuesta en esa otra pregunta pues estaría duplicando el contenido.

¿Debería publicar la respuesta en la pregunta enlazada a SOen? ¿Debería olvidarme del tema?

¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Si una pregunta tiene la misma respuesta, está duplicada y correspondería cerrarla.

Comment: Lo que se cierra es la pregunta, no la respuesta. La respuesta la podes poner tantas veces como quieras, y dejando su fuente si esta tuviese una.

Comment: @Excorpion las respuestas duplicadas se borran... si estas respondiendo lo mismo dos veces, es que la pregunta es la misma, no?

Comment: Deberiamos cerrar la pregunta que respondiste como duplicada, y poner tu respuesta en la pregunta original. No importa si esta linkeada a una publicacion en ingles.. Si la publicas en ingles, no tiene nada que ver con la de este sitio.. la asociacion es solo una referencia para nosotros...

Comment: Estoy 100% de acuerdo con @gbianchi; a mi me paso lo contrario; me marcaron como duplicada una pregunta y una respuesta; que realmente el escenario no encajaba con la pregunta original XD...